# Database trigger or constraint on commit level

Tags: database, triggers, db2, constraints, relational-database

I would like to know if there is any sort of constaint of trigger that would fire on commit level.

To elaborate a bit more on my question here is a simple example. I have a table named T and has two integer columns A (which is the primary key) and B. I want at the end of each transaction column B to contain 1 only on one row and zero on the rest of the rows. The table already contains rows and is consistent with the rule described (e.g. row with A=5 has B=1 and the rest rows all Bs are zero)

Then in a single transaction I would like to excute the following statements

- insert into T (A,B) value (8,1)
- update T set B=0 where A=5

The order of the statement execution is irrelevant.
If I had a trigger on statement level that would force the table to have exactly 1 row with 1 on column B, the first statement would fail since I add a second row with q on column B. Likewise if the order of the statements is inverse, the update statement would fail again since it leaves the table without a row with 1 on column B

If there is a trigger (or constraint) that would "fire" only at the end of the commit of the transaction, the transaction would commit flawlessly since at the end of the transaction the table will continue to have only one row with value 1 on column B ( a different one than the row that had at the begining of the transaction but still only one)

The use case I am studying will be applied on IBM DB2.

Answer (score 0):

The aim of your question is not fully clear to me.

If you understand the concept of a transaction your update and insert (both within a single transaction) would do the job.

They would work and would not leave the table inconsistent if other applications select the table with CS isolation level or a higher one.

Comment: The aim of the question is to have a way that transactions that will brake the rule will not get commited.
e.g. if the transaction had a third statement update T set B=1 where A=6 I would like this transaction to fail

Comment: Don't use triggers for that kind of application-level processing. Wrap the entire logic (regardless of the number of statements in the transaction) in a stored-procedure or anonymous block and perform whatever checks are necessary *inside* the transaction and only commit if all checks pass, otherwise rollback the whole transaction.

Comment: I know the design is problematic and the system is a legacy one, I was trying to find a way to minimize the risk of unattended alteration on the table. Thanks for the help anyway.